# Hide for 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a small script which the element should disappear for only 2 seconds and then return to appear alone, I leave the link here [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7rfypomx/)

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('img').click(function() {
                $(this).fadeOut();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(this).fadeIn();

                }, 1000);
                //$(this).toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

im trying using fade and set time but it not works

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/2adLb0ro/

Comment: When you use javascript scheduling function like setTimeout or setInterval with 'this' it is always refer window object.

Comment: Do you mean, on click `fadeOut` **all** images then `fadeIn` the image you clicked?

Comment: Am I missing something or why is the time different in title and text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` on `$(this).fadeIn();` does not point to the image anymore.

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('img').click(function() {
                var img = this; /* Store it on variable img */
                $(img).fadeOut();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(img).fadeIn(); /* Can access variable img here */
                }, 1000);
                //$(this).toggle();
            });
        });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7rfypomx/1/

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` refer to the window, you have to use `$('img').fadeIn();` to make the image appearing again

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('img').click(function() {
                $(this).fadeOut();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('img').fadeIn();

                }, 1000);
                //$(this).toggle();
            });
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ftf6wr8L/

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this it will work.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').click(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this I also updated [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7rfypomx/3/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').click(function() {
            var img = $(this);
            $(this).fadeOut();
            setTimeout(function() {
                img.fadeIn();

            }, 1000);
            //$(this).toggle();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign `$(this)` into a variable **ex.** `var ty = $(this);`

and use below line for `faceIn()` function.

```
$(ty).fadeIn();
```

Also I have updated in your existing fiddle link as well. [Check Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7rfypomx/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').click(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(function(){
               $(this).fadeIn(15000);
            });
      });
});
```

```css
    table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        
        img {
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tr>
            <th><img src="img/1.png"></th>
            <th><img src="img/2.png"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><img src="img/3.jpg"></th>
            <th><img src="img/4.jpg"></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```